# custom kernel fails to boot - 'task init:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds'

Tags: pi-3b+, kernel

I'm trying to build a custom kernel for my 3B+ (following this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md). It seems to boot without any error messages until it eventually hangs and two minutes later prints the error message

`INFO: task init:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds`

and continues to hang indefinitely. It prints out several more lines of information after this initial message. From what I can tell there's nothing especially relevant (memory addresses) but if needed I can upload a photo for more information.

How can I begin troubleshooting my kernel to fix this? I'm assuming it's a problem with my .config file, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Init is the first process started. Without it no other processes start. From your error message I think that you have either changed the init file, changed the init path or something is interfering with init starting.